# Clone() system call in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

What happens when I call clone system call by passing 0 as the stack_start? 
According to manual pages on clone it should return `-EINVAL`, but when I do that, it is showing `SIGSEGV (11)` error.

```
clone(func,NULL,0,args);
```

should return -EINVAL, but its failing with `SIGSEGV`

Answer (score 1):

According to linux kernel there is such a call chain:

[sys_clone(...stack_start...)](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/process.c#L292) -> `do_fork`

[do_fork(...stack_start...)](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/fork.c#L1580) -> `copy_process`

[copy_process(...stack_start...)](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/fork.c#L1149) -> `copy_thread`

[copy_thread(...stack_start...) on X86_32](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/process_32.c#L129) OR [copy_thread(...stack_start...) on X86_64](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/process_64.c#L148)

Looking at the `copy_thread` leads me to assumption that as this function doesn't check for `stack_start` correctness (sp argument in code) so after cloning we have a task with invalid stack pointer and first reference at zero address leads to `SIGSEGV`.

I'll suggest you to look at the glibc wrapper for clone function also.

Comment: Thank you Ilya Matveychikov, for your answer, but in kernel before calling sys_clone the start_stack pointer is being checked for NULL, and if it is NULL it is assigned to some stack pointer(May be parents stack pointer). Hence do fork call is returning the pid without segmentation fault. but when it comes to the userspace it tries to call the function which is specified in clone, for that it has to use the stack, but the stack what is being allocated doesnt belong to this child process and when it tries to access the stack, it is segment violation, hence it is getting SIGSEGV.

Comment: @LKL: Ouch! Right you are, there is a `if (!newsp) newsp = regs->sp;` at `sys_clone` statement...